Old Angular Page Gets Served
I have an Angular 16 webpage with a service worker. This page is served by a NGINX which is under my control.
Recently I have noticed that when visiting the page, the browser shows the old version. I have to refresh the webpage to get the current version.
When reopening the page after a while the old page is shown again.
I have tried to disable caching on the NGINX, but this does not work.
location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
    expires off;
    add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must revalidate";
}

I have also tried to write an UpdateService to reload the page when an Update is available. But I guess it was too late.
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UpdateAppService {
  constructor(swUpdate: SwUpdate) {
    swUpdate.versionUpdates
      .pipe(
        tap(console.log),
        filter((evt): evt is VersionReadyEvent => evt.type === 'VERSION_READY')
      )
      .subscribe((evt) => {
        document.location.reload();
      });
  }
}

This my ngsw-config.json
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(svg|cur|jpg|jpeg|png|apng|webp|avif|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

I have no meta tags to prevent caching on the index.html itself.
The url /ngsw/state seems to show an error.
NGSW Debug Info:

Driver version: 16.1.8
Driver state: SAFE_MODE (Initialization failed due to error: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON)
Latest manifest hash: none
Last update check: 12s307u



=== Idle Task Queue ===
Last update tick: 12s30u
Last update run: 7s22u
Task queue:


Debug log:


it seems that manifest file isn't shipped to the artifact that is then served by ngingx

It seems the NGINX config was the cause that the service worker was loading a wrong file. The service worker switched then to SAFE_MODE.
I have swapped the config with the following code and now it is working.
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }


